# How do I get object from HashMap respectively?

Tags: java, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

I make the personal profiles database,and I use HashMap to collect profile.

`private HashMap<String, Profile> database;`

but I want to write profile data to text files

```
PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
fileOut.println(database.size());
for(int i = 0; i < database.size();i++){
 Profile eachProfile = database.get(key);
}
```

But I don't know how to get list of key to looping 
How can I get data from HashMap respectively with another ways?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`Map.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) and extended `for`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Profile> e: database.entrySet())
{
    String s  = e.getKey();
    Profile p = e.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Map documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

You want a list of all keys which is available as `keySet()`. The `values()` and `entrySet()` methods are related.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map.keySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) to get the set of keys.
You can use [map.values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) to get the collection of values